What WAI-ARIA tags are required for an input that filters a list of checkboxes?
Let's say I have a list of checkboxes inside a <fieldset>. I want the user to be able to filter this list (given that this is pretty big), that is, you type something in this input, and only the checkboxes that match this input will be visible. What WAI-ARIA tags are required on this input and/or the checkboxes?
Or is none required with some good labeling?

Would you mind explaining what you mean by required? Required by the ARIA standard? If so, which version? 1.1 or 1.2? Required for best accessibility support as of today?

When it comes to ARIA, as I see it, this is an untypical Combobox if the value remains in the input: value="Zebra, Zoom"
The pattern is established and supported by assistive technology, and makes it clear for users of assistive technology that they need to pick options, but that an additional input helps them find (filter) options.

Typically, the initial state of a combobox is collapsed.

Contrary to the typical combobox, the associated listbox is permanently visible, so the state is not collapsed but expanded.
The ARIA standard lists such a pattern in Example 9.
The required ARIA attributes for the <input> are:

aria-expanded="true" always
aria-controls="id-of-the-listbox"
aria-autocomplete="list" to explain that a list of suggestions is provided

And those for the listbox:

role="listbox", obviously
aria-labelledby="id-of-the-label" to provide the required accessible name
role="option" on the children
or role="group", if grouping options is of interest

Here’s the trimmed code from the ARIA example.


<label id="tag_label" for="tag_combo">Tag</label>
<input type="text" id="tag_combo" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="popup_listbox">

<ul role="listbox" id="popup_listbox" aria-labelledby="tag_label">
  <li role="option">Zebra</li>
  <li role="option" id="selected_option">Zoom</li>
</ul>



As both elements (the input and the list) are within one ARIA widget (or pattern), no <fieldset> is necessary.
Keyboard navigation
Especially since the list is very long, as you mention, you definitely should manage focus, i.e. have only one focus stop, and pick options with arrow keys.

[…] authors SHOULD provide keyboard mechanisms for moving focus between the combobox element and elements contained in the popup. For example, one common convention is that Down Arrow moves focus from the input to the first focusable descendant of the popup element.

The popup element in this case is the listbox.
Otherwise, keyboard users need to step through all the option elements to continue on the page. This would fail WCAG’s Success Criterion Bypass Blocks.
If you don’t want to manage focus, you might add a skip link before the listbox:
<a href="#after-listbox">Skip options</a>
<ul role="listbox" …
  <li …
</ul>

<label id="after-listbox" …>Next input</label>

Better hide the listbox if it’s long
If the list is, as you mention, very long, it should be hidden by default.
In that case, you are using the most established combobox pattern, which is well-documented in the APG.

aria-expanded needs to be managed
along with the visibility of the listbox




<fieldset>
  <legend>Filter options</legend>
  <label for="filter">Filter options:</label>
  <input type="text" id="filter" aria-controls="checkboxes" aria-expanded="true" placeholder="Filter options...">
  <div id="checkboxes" aria-live="polite">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Option 1"> Option 1</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Option 2"> Option 2</label>
    <!-- More checkboxes -->
  </div>
</fieldset>




To make an input that filters a list of checkboxes accessible using WAI-ARIA, you should consider the following tags:

role="textbox": Assign this role to the input element to indicate
that it is a text input field.
aria-controls: Use this attribute on the input element to reference the ID of the element that contains the list of
checkboxes. This helps assistive technologies understand the
relationship between the input and the list.
aria-label or aria-labelledby: Provide a label for the input field to describe its purpose. You can use aria-label for a direct label or aria-labelledby to reference an existing label element.
aria-live="polite": Apply this to the container of the list of checkboxes to announce changes to the list as the user types in the input field.


I feel like part of this answer is in conflict with the First Rule of ARIA Use, for using ARIA to an end in itself. A real <label> is way more accessible than a aria-label, as it helps more people. role="textbox" is redundant, as it’s the input’s implicit role.
